# Trouble in displaying data to jtable from sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, jtable

```
        String sql1 = "select * from NewspaperOrder where NO=?";
        pst = sqliteconn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst.setString(1, getNo);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){  
            EditOrderTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            EditOrderTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
            EditOrderTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
            rs.close(); 
            pst.close();
        }
```

This is the block of code that I use to display my data in the table.

I just basically call all the data that has a getNo (order id) under NO (order id column in NewspaperOrder table of the database) and display it in the EditOrderTable jTable.

[image: my database]

when I run the code, for example, when getNo = "3" ... it display all of the data needed to be displayed, except the first set of data. (the "Bulletin" newspaper is missing even if it is in the database and has an order id of 3. lol)

[image: UI]

Comment: I'm thinking you should get rid of `if(rs.next()){  ` as it's likely the first thing that `DbUtils` will do when you call it

Comment: @MadProgrammer woah, thanks ! that solved the problem lol :) :)